# What parameter to serialize for saving location of WPF GridSplitter?

Tags: wpf, position, gridsplitter

I want to save the location of a `GridSplitter` used to separate two grid columns.

What should I serialize? The `Width` of the column before the splitter? The `Left` property of the splitter? The size and position of the window itself it serialized separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [GridLengthConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlengthconverter.aspx) to achieve saving the settings.

Here is a [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/08579b70-8b53-4855-9eea-333ce05491f8) which details how to make use of the class, as they were facing a similar issue.